# Why numpy.matmul with unsparse matrix is slower?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I try to optimize my python code and to save memory, I tried to use Scipy sparse matrix, but it resulted in a slower code. After digging into the problem it appears that the conversion from Scipy sparse matrix tends to slow down the computation of `np.matmul`

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Thank You.

Here is a dummy example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import time

space_size = 50
delta = 1
S = 20
Nb_seed = np.arange(200)
Distance_effect = np.random.uniform(0,1,(space_size**2, space_size**2))

Distance_effect_ = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(Distance_effect)


loc = np.random.choice(a = space_size**2, size = S * max(Nb_seed), replace = True).reshape((max(Nb_seed), S))

dist_effect_ = Distance_effect_[:, loc.reshape(max(Nb_seed) * S,)].toarray()
dist_effect_ = dist_effect_.reshape((space_size**2, max(Nb_seed), S))
dist_effect_ = np.transpose(dist_effect_,(2,0,1))

dist_effect = Distance_effect[:, loc]
dist_effect = np.transpose(dist_effect,(2,0,1))


a = np.random.uniform(0,1,(S , S,space_size**2))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    e = np.sum(np.matmul(a, dist_effect_), axis = 1).T
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    c = np.sum(np.matmul(a, dist_effect), axis = 1).T
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

time for e :
`--- 12.80036735534668 seconds ---`

time for c :
`--- 0.05399775505065918 seconds ---`

Comment: tell us about the arrays you are comparing, especially shape and dtype

Comment: Here the point is in the comparison between "dist_effect" and "dist_effect_" (yeah i should have give to those guys better names). Those are two numpy array of shape (20, 2500, 200) here, dtype is float64 here (but float32 in my main script). They only difference between them is "dist_effect_"  is extract from a sparse matrix, and it's somehow slowdown np.matmul function.
I hope i answer your question.

Comment: The `strides` are different.  The fast one is `(20000, 8, 400000)`, `(8, 31840, 160)` for the slower.    `C` contiguous copy would be `(3980000, 1592, 8)`.  The copy is slower for the `_` one (2x) but improves its `matmul`.  `copy` doesn't change the fast one's time.

Comment: If you think of  `matmul` doing a 2d `dot` on batches, then for best speed, the leading batch dimension(s) should be "outermost" in memory.  But for the slow version, that dimension is innermost, with a stride of 8, one float.

Comment: Ok thank you, i didn't know about these strides things.